# annotate method override in typescript, to make easy in code reviews

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there any naming convention, or snippet editing, or any VS code extension or any NPM libraries to tag to tag override methods in typescript. It is useful in doing code review.

Just like override syntax in Java

```
@override << ###### SOMETHING like this ######
@public String toString(){
   // your overridden code.
   return something;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The `override` keyword was added in TypeScript 4.3 as you can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#override-and-the---noimplicitoverride-flag).
Example of use:

```
class SomeComponent {
  show() {
    // ...
  }
  hide() {
    // ...
  }
}

class SpecializedComponent extends SomeComponent {
  override show() {
    // ...
  }
  override hide() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

To make it mandatory you can set `noImplicitOverride` true in your tsconfig.

Comment: Oddly enough it does not seem to work when implementing an interface

Comment: @alex-jesper Your case is different. Changing an interface method will cause errors to the classes implementing it(if your method a() now is called b() you have to implement the b method in your classes). The same is not true if you change an super class method without the keyword in the override. Check the link for more info

Comment: Sure. But it would still be relevant to express if a method in the implementing class is overriding a method or not. That is how it works in Java for instance.

Answer (score 5):

As of now there is no override keyword or decorator, **but you can write  your own decorator**:

```
const override = < Sup >( sup : { prototype : Sup } ) => <
    Field extends keyof Sup ,
    Proto extends { [ key in Field ] : Sup[ Field ] } ,
>(
    proto : Proto ,
    field : Field ,
    descr : TypedPropertyDescriptor< Sup[ Field ] > ,
)=> {}
```

And use it like this:

```
class Super {
   myMethod():void {
      console.log("Super")
  }
}

class A extends Super {
  @override(Super)
  myMethod():void {
    console.log("A")
  }
}
```

As taken from [github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2000#issuecomment-520399260).